# Django Rest-framework with iOS and android

Tags: android, ios, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I would be needing insight from everyone who is willing to support. I have a django web application and I have used the django rest framework to create the REST API and now I want to proceed to mobile development (iOS and android). The **Question** now is how do I use the REST API created to build an iOS or Android application because I am looking to build a native application. Any one can join the discussion. every tip is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use token auth as authentication mechanism,ModelViewSet as views,ModelSerializer as serializers is the fastest way.

Comment: is there any book or video reference that you could help point to?

Comment: no recommended books about DRF,just the doc.Django_By_Example(about django) is recommended.

Comment: by antonio Mele?

Comment: YES     Django_By_Example write by antonio Mele .

Comment: thanks. I understand that. what I dont know how to accomplish is the connection to iOS. Normal api we just grab and paste the api link in a code area written in swift. but this is different because I expect to handle click events and so on.

Comment: you need to design according to requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can read this post [django-rest-and-retrofit](https://medium.com/@hassanabid/developing-android-client-app-with-django-rest-framework-8d5961a49619) , this contains examples using django-rest-framework on server and retrofit on android and ios apps :).

Retrofit is a library for http conection and can handle format json.